# How to output result of a find command that excludes certain file extension

Tags: shell-script

Here is my find command:

```
find -mtime -$a | xargs zgrep -il ''$b'' | xargs zgrep -il ''$c'' | xargs zgrep -il ''$d'' | xargs zgrep -il 'ST.997' | sort -u
```

This is an example output of the above command:

```
example_file.dat.Z
example2_file.dat.Z
example2_file.dat.bak.1234567890.Z
example3_file.dat.Z
example3_file.dat.bak.Z
example4_file.dat.Z
example4_file.dat.bak.qwertyuiop.Z
```

As you see, it outputs the same files with ".bak" extension in it. What I want is to exclude/not show that file whenever I run my script. Like this example output:

```
example_file.dat.Z
example2_file.dat.Z
example3_file.dat.Z
example4_file.dat.Z
```

**EDIT:** I forgot. Sometimes it is in zip file.

Comment: can you post those variables `$a` , `$b` etc values? I suppose, that long pipeline can be optimized

Comment: You want to use actual double quotes around your variables, not 2 single quotes: use `"$b"` not `''$b''`

Comment: @glennjackman I did that but BASH reads it as a string not a variable. It's fine that way. It's not the issue.

Comment: @WashichawbachaW It would interpret it as a string (as `$b`) if you put it in _single_ quotes. The shell would expand the variable to its value if you put it in _double_ quotes.

Comment: Oh thank you. It's working. I don't know why it didn't work before. That's why I used that single quote.

Comment: Related: [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/135943)

Comment: @Wildcard considering your suggestion. I'm just new to Linux and shell scripting. It's the only thing I know for now to run my command. If you have better codes or improvements in my code, I would greatly appreciate it, or if you have references that I could read and learn to improve my script, that would be a very big help.

Comment: @WashichawbachaW the answer below by Kusalanda shows how to do it right, for reasons explained in my own answer to the "find looping" question I linked above.  Regarding references for shell scripting improvement, check my profile—I have a list there.  It doesn't take years of practice to script well, just a keen interest and willingness to learn.  Be great :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally found the answer. After long hours of experiments. haha

Here it is:

```
find -mtime -$a -type f ! -name "*.bak*" | xargs zgrep -il "$b" | xargs zgrep -il "$c" | xargs zgrep -il "$d" | xargs zgrep -il 'ST.997' | sort -u
```

Comment: that long pipeline seems to be redundant

Comment: What do you suggest? $a, $b, $c, and $d are variables with different values.

Comment: regex alternation group

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest The problem here is that something like `($a|$b|$c|$d)` would have to match on one _single_ line whereas chaining multiple `grep`s together allows for matching the expressions on _different_ lines, which I have assumed is what the OP wanted to do.

Comment: Those variables are all needed to find a specific file. If one variable doesn't exist on any file, the command won't output anything. It must be all true for the command to output a file. Yeah it's a little long and redundant, but it's the only thing I know for now. I'm only new to Linux. However, if you @RomanPerekhrest have better code than mine, I would greatly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 6):

Here's my take on this:

```
$ find . \( -name '*.bak*' -prune \) -o \
      -type f -mtime "-$a" \
      -exec zgrep -iq -e "$b" {} ';' \
      -exec zgrep -iq -e "$c" {} ';' \
      -exec zgrep -iq -e "$d" {} ';' \
      -exec zgrep -iq 'ST.997' {} ';' \
      -print | sort
```

or

```
$ find . ! -name '*.bak*' \
      -type f -mtime "-$a" \
      -exec zgrep -iq -e "$b" {} ';' \
      -exec zgrep -iq -e "$c" {} ';' \
      -exec zgrep -iq -e "$d" {} ';' \
      -exec zgrep -iq 'ST.997' {} ';' \
      -print | sort
```

Each "predicate" given to `find` will act as a "test" on the things that `find` finds. If one test fails, the next predicate will not be evaluated (there's an implicit "logical AND" between each, unless otherwise stated) and the next found name is considered instead.

1. The `\( -name "*.bak" -prune \)` bit means "if the name matches the given pattern, remove it from the search results". This *wole line* may be replaced by `! -name '*.bak*'`.
2. `-o` means "logical OR".
3. `-type f` will be true for regular files only.
4. `-mtime "-$a"` will be true for files that have a modification timestamp less than `$a` 24h-periods ago.
5. Each `-exec zgrep -q ... {} ';'` will be true if the given pattern was matched in the file, or rather, if `zgrep` exits with a zero exit status (which `zgrep -q` does if a match is found, but it won't produce any output). The `-e` flag to `zgrep` will force the values of the given variables to act as patterns (this matters if any of them starts with `-`).
6. `-print` will output the name (this predicate is always "true").

If you are unwilling to change the *whole* command, a hacked fix would be to simpy pass the result of your original command through `grep -v '\.bak'` or `grep -vF '.bak'`, but as your command currently stands it will have issues with files that have exotic filenames (names containing newlines, for example).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I prefer an easier way. :)

Comment: @WashichawbachaW Fair enough. Then just go with what I wrote at the end: pipe your original command through `grep -vF '.bak'`.

Comment: check my answer below :)

Comment: There is no purpose to the `-u` flag in `sort -u` here.  I don't *think* there's any purpose to the `sort` command at all here, but I *know* there's no purpose to the `-u` flag.  Still, +1 for doing it right (i.e. using `find` instead of long `xargs` pipelines).

Comment: @Wildcard I was concentrating on the `find` bits and didn't even consider the `sort`, but you're absolutely right; There is no reason to do a `sort -u` since there will be no duplicated file paths.