# How to find a file using multiple pattern

Tags: shell-script, grep, find, filenames

I'd like to find a file using multiple patterns.

This is my original command: But it's long to type and `xargs zgrep` is being redundant. Imagine if I have 10 or more patterns to input?

```
find -mtime -$a -type f ! -name "*.bak*" | xargs zgrep -il "$b" | xargs zgrep -il "$c" | xargs zgrep -il "$d" | xargs zgrep -il 'ST.997' | sort -u
```

I wanted like less characters to type like for example:

```
find -mtime -$a -type f ! -name "*.bak*" | xargs zgrep -il "$b && $c && $d" | sort -u
```

**EDIT:** If you notice the patterns are associated with `$`. That's because the command is inside a script and those variables has string/numeric values.

I will use this to improve my script especially its run time.

Comment: You mean multiple pattern in a whole file or only if found in one line of a file?

Comment: Can you post all of your script?

Comment: @AFSHIN, I kinda didn't get your question. I want to find the file that has all the pattern I inputted in the command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to output result of a find command that excludes certain file extension](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/387596/how-to-output-result-of-a-find-command-that-excludes-certain-file-extension)

Comment: @Kusalananda, while they're about the same code, the questions are completely different. This one is about finding several patterns in compressed files, the other one is to exclude files from a `find` search.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Agreed. Vote retracted.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to avoid having to decompress the file again and again for each pattern, you could do:

```
PATTERNS='foo
bar
baz' find . -mtime -"$a" -type f ! -name "*.bak*" -exec awk -v q=\' '
  function shquote(s) {
    gsub(q, q "\\" q q, s)
    return q s q
  }
  BEGIN {
    n = split(ENVIRON["PATTERNS"], pats, "\n")
    for (arg = 1; arg < ARGC; arg++) {
      file = ARGV[arg]
      cmd = "gzip -dcf < " shquote(file)
      for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) notfound[pats[i]]
      left = n
      while (left && (cmd | getline line) > 0) {
        for (pat in notfound) {
          if (line ~ pat) {
            if (!--left) {
              print file
              break
            }
            delete notfound[pat]
          }
        }
      }
      close(cmd)
    }
    exit
  }' {} +
```

Note that the patterns are taken as **`awk`** patterns, that's similar to the extended regular expressions supported by `grep -E`/`egrep`. For case insensitive matching, you can add a `-v IGNORECASE=1` if using GNU `awk`, or portably change to:

```
PATTERNS='foo
bar
baz' find . -mtime -"$a" -type f ! -name "*.bak*" -exec awk -v q=\' '
  function shquote(s) {
    gsub(q, q "\\" q q, s)
    return q s q
  }
  BEGIN {
    n = split(tolower(ENVIRON["PATTERNS"]), pats, "\n")
    for (arg = 1; arg < ARGC; arg++) {
      file = ARGV[arg]
      cmd = "gzip -dcf < " shquote(file)
      for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) notfound[pats[i]]
      left = n
      while (left && (cmd | getline line) > 0) {
        line = tolower(line)
        for (pat in notfound) {
          if (line ~ pat) {
            if (!--left) {
              print file
              break
            }
            delete notfound[pat]
          }
        }
      }
      close(cmd)
    }
    exit
  }' {} +
```

(assuming the patterns don't have non-standard ERE extensions like `\S`, which would be converted to `\s`).

You could put that `awk` command in a `zgrep-many` script to make it easier to use. Something like:

```
#! /bin/sh -

usage() {
  cat >&2 << EOF
Usage: $0 [-e <pattern>] [-f <file] [-i] [pattern] files

List the files for which all the given patterns are matched.
EOF
  exit 1
}

ignorecase= 
PATTERNS=
export PATTERNS
NL='
'
sep=

while getopts e:f:i opt; do
  case $opt in
    (e) PATTERNS=$PATTERNS$sep$OPTARG; sep=$NL;;
    (f) PATTERNS=$PATTERNS$sep$(cat < "$OPTARG") || exit; sep=$NL;;
    (i) ignorecase='tolower(';;
    (*) usage;;
  esac
done
shift "$((OPTIND - 1))"
if [ -z "$PATTERNS" ]; then
  [ "$#" -gt 0 ] || usage
  PATTERN=$1; shift
fi

[ "$#" -eq 0 ] && exit

exec awk -v q=\' '
  function shquote(s) {
    gsub(q, q "\\" q q, s)
    return q s q
  }
  BEGIN {
    n = split('"$ignorecase"'ENVIRON["PATTERNS"]'"${ignorecase:+)}"', pats, "\n")
    for (arg = 1; arg < ARGC; arg++) {
      file = ARGV[arg]
      cmd = "gzip -dcf < " shquote(file)
      for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) notfound[pats[i]]
      left = n
      while (left && (cmd | getline line) > 0) {
        '"${ignorecase:+line = tolower(line)}"'
        for (pat in notfound) {
          if (line ~ pat) {
            if (!--left) {
              print file
              break
            }
            delete notfound[pat]
          }
        }
      }
      close(cmd)
    }
    exit
  }' "$@"
```

To be used as:

```
find ... -exec zgrep-many -ie foo -e bar -e baz {} +
```

for instance.

Answer (score 2):

`grep` doesn't have AND option for matching multiple patterns, but you can essentially OR match patterns using `|`. If you use extended syntax, you could combine multiple patterns with all their combinations:

```
a.*b.*c|a.*c.*b|b.*a.*c|b.*c.*a|c.*a.*b|c.*b.*a
```

But its probably not a good idea if you got more than two patterns since the number of combinations goes up quickly.

You could combine your `zgrep` commands using `-exec`. Use quiet option `-q` for every `zgrep` except the last one (which prints the filename if it and all previous greps found a match).

```
find -mtime -$a -type f ! -name "*.bak*"      \
        -exec zgrep -iq "$b" {} \;            \
        -exec zgrep -iq "$c" {} \;            \
        -exec zgrep -il "$d" {} \; | sort
```

Comment: How to make that command into a variable? My command is inside a script and I use it as a value to a variable like `output=$(command in here)`. I use it to further call to another function in my script. And does it speeds up the run time of the command?

Comment: It executes the right file but it takes longer to output than my original command. Do you have anymore better shorter to type command? My original command takes only 16 seconds to finish. Yours takes 39-45 secs. Tha's more than twice as slow compared to mine

Comment: No, I don't think there is any way this is going to be faster since `zgrep` is executed separately for each match and since the next `-exec` depends on return value of previous `-exec` passing more filenames in find isn't likely going to work.

Answer (score 1):

You might use `find` with a command running three `zgrep`-s like

```
  find -mtime -$a -type f ! -name "*.bak*"      \
       -exec zgrep -q {} "$b" \; \
       -a   -exec zgrep -q {} "$c" \; \
       -a   -exec zgrep -q {} "$d" \; \
    | sort
```

You could also collect first the names of files to `grep` e.g.

```
 find -mtime -$a -type f ! -name "*.bak*" > /tmp/file-list
```

(assuming your file names are nice, without spaces)

then loop on every line in `/tmp/file-list`

At last, you could write a script in another language (`awk`, Python, ...)

and to avoid typing, you might define a shell function.

Comment: Same as above answer. I think, I should still go to my old code. It executes faster than this.